# How to split string with pattern without losing any text?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have problem with splitting string with pattern. I know that I can use `String.prototype.split` to split the string. However if I use it, I lose the delimiters.

For example

```
const text = '{user} foo bar {time} test test';
const arr = text.split(/\{[a-z]*\}/)
// arr = ["", " foo bar ", " test test"]
```

What I expect is `["{user}", " foo bar ", "{time}", " test test"]`

Is it possible to achieve with `split`?

Comment: Use `text.split(/(\{[a-z]*})/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: You don't need any complex RegExp. Just try this `text.split(" ");`

Comment: @Krusader It won't work due to `" foo bar "` and `" test test"`

Comment: Thanks that worked @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2):

Try the following match:

```js
const text = '{user} foo bar {time} test test';
const arr = text.match(/\{.*?\}|\b[\w\s]+\b/g);
// arr = ["", " foo bar ", " test test"]

console.log(arr)
```